# Map image to irregular polygon?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, transform, textures

Say the user taps 4 spots on the iphone, defining an irregular 4 sided polygon (in 2d space).  Is there a way to map/fit a (potentially highly distorted) image onto this shape, without using OpenGL?

Something like:
[image]

Is my only option to somehow calculate the 3d space that my irregular 4 sided shape sits in (based on where the tapped 2d points sit), create an OpenGL plane in that space, and map my texture to it flatly?  Seems like there should be an easier way...

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** After diving into OpenGL I'm almost there... but I still can't get the texture to distort correctly.  The triangulation seems to be messing with the texture mapping:

[image: http://twitpic.com/3t278p/full]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer your question completely, but one thing I would say is that you don't need to think about any conversion / mapping to 3D. Using OpenGL you can easily draw the shape in 2D and have the texture mapped as you desire. No need for any fancy maths or conversions. It's no more complicated than drawing a rectangle. OpenGL doesn't care that your 4-sided shape isn't actually rectangular.

Comment: Ahh I hadn't thought about OpenGL as a solution for 2d drawing - thanks Andrew. I'll try it out...

Comment: After searching around a bit all I can turn up are tutorials on mapping a texture to a flat rectangle or a primitive of some kind - any idea where I can learn about achieving the type of transformation I'm looking for? (aside from reading the entire Redbook)?

Comment: The procedure for doing what you want to do is exactly the same as for a rectangle. Set-up four vertices to represent your shape, set-up four UV points to represent each corner of your rectangular texture, and voila -- OpenGL will squeeze and stretch your texture to fill your shape. (Apologies for vagueness but I'm not familiar with OpenGL on iPhone so I can't provide example code. Does the iPhone implementation of OpenGL work with glBegin/glEnd etc, or buffers?)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Andrew.  I spent all day getting up to speed with openGL, and I'm close to cracking this.  Right now the triangulation of my model (which is apparently required in opengl es) is really messing with my texture mapping...  http://twitpic.com/3t278p , but if I can get this figured out I've got it!  Also, I don't see glBengin/glEnd in the specification http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/